# Getting error message eventhough email is send successfully -Angular

Tags: angular, express, email, nodemailer

I send an email with my angular application.
Even though the e-mail is sent I always get the error.
More specifically I get this message:

```
modal.component.ts:361 Error sending email: 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:3000/send-email', ok: false, …}
error
: 
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'E', "Email sent"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>…, text: 'Email sent successfully'}
headers
: 
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
: 
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/send-email"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
url
: 
"http://localhost:3000/send-email"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
```

Here is my code:

```
this.emailService.sendEmail(this.name, this.email, this.message).subscribe(
      () => {
        // Email sent successfully
        console.log('Email sent!');
        // Display a success message to the user, or perform any other action
      },
      (error) => {
        // Error occurred while sending email
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        // Display an error message to the user, or perform any other action
      }
    );
```

Is any way I can get the status of the error message? or fix the code?
Thank you!

Comment: It's looks like the response of your API (who send the email) is a plain text, not a JSON. So, in httptClient.post you need indicate Angular that you expect a string adding `{ observe: 'response' }`: `this.httpClient.post(..your-url..,data,{observe:'response'})`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server#reading-the-full-response) -it's related to get but it's the same when we want received a response from a post-

Comment: @Eliseo make that an answer 

Comment: show the server side code from express route here: `http://localhost:3000/send-email`, you probably have `res.send('Email sent successfully');`, which sends text response, so change that to `res.json({result:'Email sent successfully'});` which will send json response, and then you can read the result property and show it to the user, for example: `this.message = response.body?.result;....`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, just do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like the response of your API (who send the email) is a plain text, not a JSON. So, in httptClient.post you need indicate Angular that you expect a string adding `{ observe: 'response' }`:

```
this.httpClient.post(..your-url..,data,{observe:'response'}),
```

See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server#reading-the-full-response) -it's related to get but it's the same when we want received a response from a post-